# How to achieve digitally adjustable supply rail sover a wide range (low up to 300V)?

Tags: power-supply, amplifier, switch-mode-power-supply, class-d

I need to be able to vary the supply rail over a wide range (low voltage up to 300V DC). Current consumption will be from 1 mA up to 40mA. The thing will be powered by AC mains 120V. I am wondering what is the best way to achieve a DC rail that can be adjusted digitally through a microcontroller, that stays stable enough with current output 1 to 40 mA. I was thinking of using a buck and drive it with PWM but I've been told this won't be good enough if output current is not stable. Thank you.

Comment: How much precision do you want? How much stability? Cost and space requirements? Buck/boost with a linear "fine tuning" stage is probably the best answer but most complex.

Comment: Also, how low is low voltage?

Comment: For a one off, I would just go linear with a digital reference input from a DAC. Maybe use relay tap switching for better thermals

Comment: Low current is a bit of a challenge for any buck/forward topology. With 40:1 ratio, you will most likley pass from CCM to DCM. Fully manageable to keep it stable engough, save for unknown boltage and current ripple requirements.

Answer (score -1):

first stage ac to dc playback smps , ac to 300v dc , topswiches devices recommended for simplicity.
second stage , dc-dc buck smps controlled by microcontroller with 12 or 16 bit timers for pwm for more precise control.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE but this is a rather poor first post and is unlikely to be a useful answer. You can edit it to explain what you mean by "first stage", "playback", "topswitches (sic) devices" and add diagrams or schematics to assist in the explanation. Your lack of correct capitalisation and punctuation just makes it worse. Have a look around the site and look at the quality of posts that attract high votes.